# Infinitive verb at the beginning of a clause

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, infinitives, clauses

I found the following passage in the story [“On Film” by Charlie Davenport](https://www.chillingtalesfordarknights.com/2014/10/11/on-film-by-charlie-davenport-otis-jirys-creepypasta-crypt/) -

> I had fully intended to leave them in the hotel, to let some poor maid
>   working for minimum wage and whatever tips tourists decided to give
>   her, deal with the last of my burdens.

Should there be a *to* before the word deal in above paragraph? I mean should  it  be like-

> I had fully intended to leave them in the hotel, to let some poor maid
>   working for minimum wage and whatever tips tourists decided to give
>   her, ***to deal*** with the last of my burdens.

Comment: There should be a comma after "maid"

Comment: @dockeryZ I m not allowed to add something, I quoted as I found it. What about my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should really be two commas around the [participle phrase](http://www.studyandexam.com/types-of-phrase.html) *working for minimum wage and whatever tips tourists decided to give her*.

If we remove the phrase (which is not essential), we have:

> I had fully intended to leave them in the hotel, to let some poor maid
>   deal with the last of my burdens.

This makes sense. It is the maid that is going to deal with the narrator's problems. If we want to include the phrase, then we should set it apart from the rest of the sentence with commas in order to make the sentence easier for the reader to parse:

> I had fully intended to leave them in the hotel, to let some poor maid,
>   working for minimum wage and whatever tips tourists decided to give
>   her, deal with the last of my burdens.

It may be permissible to omit the commas:

> I had fully intended to leave them in the hotel, to let some poor maid
>   working for minimum wage and whatever tips tourists decided to give
>   her deal with the last of my burdens.

However, the reader has to work harder to parse the sentence correctly. The commas are there for a reason.

I do not have enough expertise to state categorically that the original sentence is ungrammatical. It may not be. However, it seems to me that the author has only done half a job in helping the reader to parse his writing. He might as well have omitted the final comma.

It may be possible that the author deliberately omitted the leading comma in order to force the reader to parse the participle phrase and thus take greater notice of the content. With the leading and trailing commas included, it becomes easier for the reader to skim the sentence and effectively ignore the participle phrase. However, I suspect that the author has just been careless.

Having worked through all this, I feel reasonably safe in saying that *working for minimum wage and whatever tips tourists decided to give her* should be delimited by commas because it is a participle phrase.

Adding an infinitive is wrong since, if we omit the participle phrase, we would have:

> I had fully intended to leave them in the hotel, to let some poor maid
>   to deal with the last of my burdens.

and that is definitely ungrammatical.

Comment: So, 'to' is not required?? looks a strange construction!

Comment: No. The sentence is incorrect but adding an infinitive is not going to fix it.

Comment: Do you want me to give the link of the story where i got this passage? please  add your comment to your answer (that the sentence is incorrect)

Comment: By all means, but put the link in your question, not in an additional comment.

Comment: By the way, have u read the story, it is full of confusion, isn't it?

Comment: @MikeSQ - I must confess that I stopped when I found the quoted text. I'll try and read it through when I have a spare moment. I'll have to print it out, though. I can't read for pleasure using a screen.